# What is the appropiate http status code to give, when a user is using an unallowed authorization method?

Tags: api, httprequest

For context, I am working on an API in postman, where an http request can be authorized using an api key or basic authentication.

I was using 401 as a status code if a different authorization method was used.
Is there a more suitable status code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the appropriate status code would be 405 - method not allowed.
But also status code 401 - unauthorized would work.
More accurate would be the 405.